# Converting SQL query to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query where I am getting value of column in list form.

```
Select STUFF((
              Select Distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(visit_count) 
              From arms 
              Where armId= '@armIdValue'
              FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
             ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
```

the value of `visit_count` column is 5, so I get result like this:

```
[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]
```

I tried to turn this query to run in MySQL but it's not accepting FOR XML.
Do any solutions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `group_concat()`

```
select group_concat(concat('[',visit_count,']')
from arms WHERE armId= 12 group by armid
```

Comment: it doesn't give result in form of list, it simply returns 5

Comment: could you please add some sample data in your question @MohammadShahbaz

Comment: I have a table where 1 column is armId and other is visit_count, data is armId=12 and visit_count=5

Comment: @MohammadShahbaz, I've updated the answer - you can check but sample data is more appreciated

Comment: got 1,2,3,4,5 as result. only thing which i am not getting is the  [ ]

Comment: @MohammadShahbaz, check now

Answer (score 1):

You can try the Following Query.

MSSQL:

```
DECLARE @col nvarchar(MAX);
SELECT @col = COALESCE(@col,'') +'['+visit_count +']'+ ',' 
From arms Where armId= '@armIdValue'
SELECT @col
```

MYSQL :

```
SELECT armId,GROUP_CONCAT(visit_count)
 FROM arms Where armId= '@armIdValue'
 GROUP BY armId
```

Comment: getting Error: DECLARE col nvarchar(MAX) Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE col nvarchar(MAX)' at line 1 0.000 sec

Comment: col is @col in the above statement

Comment: how can i run these threes statements together in mysql, it's giving me error

Comment: FUNCTION QUOTENAME does not exist 0.000 sec